# cython "Hello World" Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, gcc, cython

```
$cat say.py
print('Hello World!')

$python --version
Python 2.7.11+

$python say.py
Hello World!

$cython --version
Cython version 0.23.4

$cython say.py
$gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs python` -o say say.c -lpython2.7 -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl -fPIC -shared

$./say
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc` compiles a *module* which can be imported by python:

```
% cython say.py
% gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs python` -o say.so say.c -lpython2.7 -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl -fPIC -shared
% /bin/rm say.py   # make sure we aren't just importing say.py
% ls -l say*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 unutbu unutbu 19693 Apr  8 07:52 say.so
-rw-rw-r-- 1 unutbu unutbu 68614 Apr  8 07:52 say.c

% python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import say
Hello World!
>>>
```

See also ["Building Cython Code"](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html) for other better ways to build Cython code.